# css selector works in browser but not in Selenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selenium, css-selectors

I am doing test automation with Selenium and usually use css selectors to locate the elements. Recently however, I have encountered a strange issue. I noticed that in some cases the css selector works fine when I test in the browser console. For example, to select a specific button out of many, I do:

```
(1) $("div.v-app[id^='v-discussions'] .v-button-caption:contains('Add')")
```

But when I actually use in Selenium it returns an error:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector div.v-app[id^='v-discussions'] .v-button-caption:contains('Add') is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

I also tried that string with `querySelector` and I get "Illegal string" error:

```
(2) document.querySelectorAll("div.v-app[id^='v-discussions'] .v-button-caption:contains('Add')")
```

Why that might happen?

P.S.

This is how each one of the elements looks like:

```
<span class="v-button-caption">Add Comment</span>
```

Comment: Are you using pure webdriverjs or protractor? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Hi, no I am using FirefoxDriver. Thank you.

Comment: Try it without `:contains`

Comment: @Tushar not sure I understand what you mean. If I try it as is but without `:contains` it will not be a valid expression. `$("div.v-app[id^='v-discussions'] .v-button-caption('Add')")`

Comment: @EugeneS `:contains` is jQuery pseudo-selector, not javascript/CSS's

Comment: @Tushar I see. But I am not sure how can I do the same without the `:contains`. Please have a look at the example I just added to the question. There are many of elements like these and I have to select one with `Add Comment` text. Do you see other way I can pick that element without using `:contains`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well go for :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("v-button-caption"));
```

I use it in Selenium Webdriver and works fine for me

Comment: Please read the question again. In my case it is not a single element that I am trying to locate but to pick a specific element from a list of elements.

Comment: for all the selectors you can use this method and this command does the same as you are saying, it picks up a specific element from the bunch of the elements on the page .. every element has their own specific and unique id and by that it gets selected